# Kernel stops working after a while, when fitting the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

I'm trying to run the code provided from TensorFlow for [image classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification). I'm using the exact same code provided by TensorFlow, so I don't share it here. The code runs perfectly to the point where it fits the model. It prints "Epoch" once, then kernel shuts down and says "An error occurred while starting kernel." As the error message it produces:

````
2021 21:19:59.749095: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021 21:20:02.178383: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021 21:20:02.198734: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.62GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021 21:20:02.198906: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021 21:20:02.204104: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021 21:20:02.204165: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021 21:20:02.207305: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021 21:20:02.208428: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021 21:20:02.213539: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021 21:20:02.215481: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021 21:20:02.216199: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021 21:20:02.216287: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021 21:20:02.216750: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance‑critical operations: AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021 21:20:02.217490: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.62GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021 21:20:02.217546: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021 21:20:02.708850: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021 21:20:02.708874: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264] 0 
2021 21:20:02.708880: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0: N 
2021 21:20:02.709035: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5484 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021 21:20:04.004652: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021 21:20:05.150123: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll```
````

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the same given code in colab. It ran successfully without any error. Please find the related code [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/7b5ac80c3aae2a5a7bc745f0e32d3e73/image-classification-on-flowers-data.ipynb) here.

However, They are just the information message as they are prefixed with `I`, if it is the error message they would be prefixed with `E` or `W` for warnings are as shown below:

```
2020-12-30 21:30:27.549172: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cupti64_101.dll

2020-12-30 21:30:27.599977: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 37171200 exceeds 10% of system memory.

2021-12-30 21:30:27.704083: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1307] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
```

You can surpass these warnings using below code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```